# Centos 6.3 - Error during filesystem check (/opt)

Tags: centos, filesystems, centos6, fsck

When I rebooted my server I got the following error:
[image]

What can I do to get the server back up? I tried running `lvremove /dev/vg1/snaps` but get the message: `File based locking initialization failed`

I tried running `fsck -fp /dev/vg1/snaps` and that results in:
`/dev/mapper/vg1-snaps: 11/65536 files (0.0% non-contiguous), 12635/262144 blocks`
Rebooting after this saw the same problem

I don't know if this is good or bad. There is no data on that partition (os just installed). Any ideas what I can do to fix or remove this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do in this case is comment out the `/etc/fstab` entry for the offending partition. You may need to remount the root filesystem as read-write:

`mount -o remount,rw /`

Then edit the `/etc/fstab` and place a comment (#) on the line of the snaps partition. Save and reboot.

Comment: thanks yah, I did have to remount the / filesystem before I could change /etc/fstab, then just comment out the relevant line.

Answer (score 0):

Ewwhite's answer is excellent; if that doesn't work, given that you mentioned it's a fresh install, would be to try another fresh install (and be very, very careful about how you set up partitions.)  Sometimes time fixing a problem by popping the hood is 3x > than simply resetting the engine.